# Adding a / as an end delimeter on Liquibase Oracle SQL statement

Tags: liquibase

While using Liquibase feature, I extended liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.CreateIndexGenerator class to convert this command

```
create index indexI on tableT(columnC)
```

into something like this:

```
declare
  index_already_exists exception;
  pragma exception_init(index_already_exists, -955);
  --
begin
  execute immediate 'create index indexI on tableT(columnC)';
exception
  when index_already_exists then
    dbms_output.put_line('Warning: Index indexI already exists');
end;
```

to make it idempotent and create some new validations.

It is working perfectly when using **mvn liquibase:update**. But, when generating the SQL using **mvn liquibase:updateSQL** a final / (slash) is missing.

Looking at Liquibase sourcecode I found out that the class *LoggingExecutor* used to have what I need on method *outputStatement*

```
} else if (database instanceof OracleDatabase) {
    output.write(StreamUtil.getLineSeparator());
    output.write("/");
```

I tried to add a final / (slash) after the *end;* if, but it becomes like this :

```
end;
/;
```

which is invalid PLSQL code

Is there another way to add a final / on the SQL generated code, or set the / as an end delimeter ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I also need to add / between statements to maintain compatibility with existing software.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending CreateIndexGenerator you could instead override CreateIndexChange.generateStatements() to return a RawSqlStatement with your SQL. That allows you to better set the end delimiter and may work better with the LoggingExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using liquibase 3.4.2 and the end delimiter / is recognized automatically. When I mean automatically you don't have to use the property endDelimiter in the declaration of the changeset. It turns out that in some older versions of liquibase a bug was introduced during the parsing. 
Please check http://www.liquibase.org/2015/06/liquibase-3-4-0-released.html
and you will see that they fix the issue https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2227. This issue was affecting the version 3.3.2. 
So I suggest you to use a newer version or specify correctly the endDelimiter property in the declaration of the changeset.

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html